# How to copy new object java

Tags: java

On my program I want to save some state using stack.
But all object in stack are always the same(the lest i enterd).
here is my Save code:

```
    public void saveState(){
    state.setMatrix(temp.clone()); //temp is int[][]
    state.setScore(score); //score is int
    State newgaGameState = new State(state); //copy consructor
    stack.push(newgaGameState);
}
```

I guess i need to copy the state because the stack save the reference.
How I need to do it??
what I did wrong?

thanks.

Comment: Copy constructor can help

Comment: I tried to use copt construcor. see above

Comment: This is no C++, there is no compiler-generated copy constructor doing the magic. You have to implement a deep copy.

Comment: Did you implement copy constructor in your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [deep copy](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-clone-shallow-copy-and-deep-copy/). So, you can do one of the following:

- use state.clone() (of course, you have to check if it creates a deep copy)
- serialize and then deserialize object you want to copy
- implement this by yourself

Answer (score 0):

You are adding information to `state`, and then you save `gameState`. If this is not a typo, it seems you are not really saving anything new.

Answer (score -3):

Use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`;

WriteObject

```
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file-full-path);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);   
    oos.writeObject(your-object);
    oos.close();
```

Read Object

```
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file-full-path);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
    Your-Class yourObject = (Your-Class) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
```